# Firefox Event propagation on click while holding keydown problem

Tags: javascript, firefox, event-handling

I am implementing table row multi-selection, which should work like this:
Clicking on the first line, then hold Shift + click on the bottom line should select all the lines in between.
I also use custom checkboxes, which are combinations of checkbox + label basically. I also take advantage of event propagation and bind event handler only on the table only.

The problem is that event won't bubble from the label to the input while holding Shift key on Firefox.

```js
var lastCheckedRow = null;

$("table").click(function handleRowCheckboxClick(e) {
  var $t = $(e.target);
  // check if target is checkbox, otherwise ignore event ( on label )
  if ($t.is(":checkbox")) {
    var $cb = $t.is(":checkbox") ? $t : $t.siblings("input.mof-cell-checkbox");
    // if not disabled
    if (!$cb.prop("disabled")) {
      if ($cb.hasClass("mof-cell-checkbox")) {
        if (window.getSelection().empty) {
          // Chrome
          window.getSelection().empty();
        }
        checkBoxClickHandler($cb, e.shiftKey);
      }
    }
  }
});

function checkBoxClickHandler($checkBoxInput, wasShiftPressed) {
  var isChecked = $checkBoxInput.prop("checked");
  $checkBoxInput
    .closest("table > tbody > tr")
    .toggleClass("row-selected", isChecked);

  if (
    lastCheckedRow &&
    lastCheckedRow.index() ==
      $checkBoxInput.closest("table > tbody > tr").index()
  ) {
    lastCheckedRow = null;
    return;
  }

  if (!lastCheckedRow) {
    lastCheckedRow = $checkBoxInput.closest("table > tbody > tr");
    return;
  }

  if (wasShiftPressed) {
    var start = $checkBoxInput.closest("table > tbody > tr").index();
    var end = lastCheckedRow.index();
    var $trs = $checkBoxInput
      .closest("table")
      .find("tbody > tr")
      .slice(Math.min(start, end), Math.max(start, end) + 1);
    if (
      lastCheckedRow.find(".mof-cell-checkbox").prop("checked") == isChecked
    ) {
      $trs.each(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("row-selected", isChecked);
        $(this).find(".mof-cell-checkbox").prop("checked", isChecked);
      });
    } else {
      $trs.each(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("row-selected", !isChecked);
        $(this).find(".mof-cell-checkbox").prop("checked", !isChecked);
      });
    }
  }

  lastCheckedRow = $checkBoxInput.closest("table > tbody > tr");
}
```

```css
.custom-checkbox {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-top: -0.075rem;
  margin-bottom: -0.075rem;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  min-height: 1.45rem;
}

.custom-control-input {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
}

.custom-checkbox .custom-control-label::before {
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.custom-control-label::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.1rem;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 1.25rem;
  height: 1.25rem;
  pointer-events: none;
  content: "";
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  background-color: #dee2e6;
}

.custom-checkbox .custom-control-input:checked ~ .custom-control-label::before {
  background-color: #2196f3;
}

.custom-control-input:checked ~ .custom-control-label::before {
  border: none;
}
.custom-control-input:checked ~ .custom-control-label::before {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #2196f3;
}

.custom-checkbox .custom-control-input:checked ~ .custom-control-label::after {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath fill='%23fff' d='M6.564.75l-3.59 3.612-1.538-1.55L0 4.26 2.974 7.25 8 2.193z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
.custom-control-label::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.1rem;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 1.25rem;
  height: 1.25rem;
  content: "";
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col width="30px">
  </colgroup>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="custom-checkbox custom-control">
          <input class="custom-control-input mof-cell-checkbox mof-cell-checkbox-item form-control" id="0__checkBox" type="checkbox" value="true">
          <label class="custom-control-label" for="0__checkBox"></label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>1
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="custom-checkbox custom-control">
          <input class="custom-control-input mof-cell-checkbox mof-cell-checkbox-item form-control" id="1__checkBox" type="checkbox" value="true">
          <label class="custom-control-label" for="1__checkBox"></label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>2
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="custom-checkbox custom-control">
          <input class="custom-control-input mof-cell-checkbox mof-cell-checkbox-item form-control" id="2__checkBox" type="checkbox" value="true">
          <label class="custom-control-label" for="2__checkBox"></label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>3
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

the demo works on Chrome, but not on Firefox.
Any ideas of why it is happening? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

shift+click or ctrl+click on a label won't work in Firefox. Please refer their reopened bug [If you shift+click or ctrl+click on a label for a checkbox, checkbox is not checked.](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=559506).

To make it work, you need to customize your check boxes without using `<label>` tag.

Integrated custom checkboxt labels, which is working fine. Tested in latest Chrome and Firefox.

```js
var lastCheckedRow = null;

$(document).on('click', '.mof-cell-checkbox', function handleRowCheckboxClick(e) {
  var $t = $(e.target);
  // check if target is checkbox, otherwise ignore event ( on label )
  if ($t.is(":checkbox")) {
    var $cb = $t.is(":checkbox") ? $t : $t.siblings("input.mof-cell-checkbox");
    // if not disabled
    if (!$cb.prop("disabled")) {
      if ($cb.hasClass("mof-cell-checkbox")) {
        if (window.getSelection().empty) {
          // Chrome
          window.getSelection().empty();
        }
        checkBoxClickHandler($cb, e.shiftKey);
      }
    }
  }
});

function checkBoxClickHandler($checkBoxInput, wasShiftPressed) {
  var isChecked = $checkBoxInput.prop("checked");
  $checkBoxInput
    .closest("table > tbody > tr")
    .toggleClass("row-selected", isChecked);

  if (
    lastCheckedRow &&
    lastCheckedRow.index() ==
      $checkBoxInput.closest("table > tbody > tr").index()
  ) {
    lastCheckedRow = null;
    return;
  }

  if (!lastCheckedRow) {
    lastCheckedRow = $checkBoxInput.closest("table > tbody > tr");
    return;
  }

  if (wasShiftPressed) {
    var start = $checkBoxInput.closest("table > tbody > tr").index();
    var end = lastCheckedRow.index();
    var $trs = $checkBoxInput
      .closest("table")
      .find("tbody > tr")
      .slice(Math.min(start, end), Math.max(start, end) + 1);
    if (
      lastCheckedRow.find(".mof-cell-checkbox").prop("checked") == isChecked
    ) {
      $trs.each(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("row-selected", isChecked);
        $(this).find(".mof-cell-checkbox").prop("checked", isChecked);
      });
    } else {
      $trs.each(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("row-selected", !isChecked);
        $(this).find(".mof-cell-checkbox").prop("checked", !isChecked);
      });
    }
  }

  lastCheckedRow = $checkBoxInput.closest("table > tbody > tr");
}
```

```css
.custom-checkbox {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

.custom-checkbox > * {
    position: absolute;
}

.custom-checkbox-visible {
  width: 1.25rem;
  height: 1.25rem;
    margin: 2px;
    background-color: #dee2e6;
}

.custom-checkbox > input {
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translatex(-50%) translatey(-50%);
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
  background-color: #dee2e6;
}

.custom-checkbox > input:checked + .custom-checkbox-visible {
    background: #2196f3;
  background-color: #2196f3;
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath fill='%23fff' d='M6.564.75l-3.59 3.612-1.538-1.55L0 4.26 2.974 7.25 8 2.193z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col width="30px">
  </colgroup>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="custom-checkbox custom-control">
          <input class="custom-control-input mof-cell-checkbox mof-cell-checkbox-item form-control" id="0__checkBox" type="checkbox" value="true">
          <div class="custom-checkbox-visible"></div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>1
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="custom-checkbox custom-control">
          <input class="custom-control-input mof-cell-checkbox mof-cell-checkbox-item form-control" id="1__checkBox" type="checkbox" value="true"/>
          <div class="custom-checkbox-visible"></div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>2
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="custom-checkbox custom-control">
          <input class="custom-control-input mof-cell-checkbox mof-cell-checkbox-item form-control" id="2__checkBox" type="checkbox" value="true">
          <div class="custom-checkbox-visible"></div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>3
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for reference to FF bug, which is 11 yrs old! 

Comment: Yes, but recently 3 months back it was reopened.